# How to read content of JSON file uploaded to google cloud storage using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-cloud-storage

I manually upload the JSON file to google cloud storage by creating a new project. I am able to read the metadata for a file but I don't know how to read the JSON content.

The code I used to read the metadata is:

```
var Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = Storage({
    keyFilename: 'service-account-file-path',
    projectId: 'project-id'
});
storage
    .bucket('project-name')
    .file('file-name')
    .getMetadata()
    .then(results => {
        console.log("results is", results[0])
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('ERROR:', err);
    });
```

Can someone guide me to the way to read the JSON file content?

Comment: never used this but it seems like you need to download it to me

Comment: maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45331443/how-to-access-objects-in-google-cloud-storage) can help you

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've used the following code to read a json file from Cloud Storage:

```
    'use strict';
    const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
    const storage = Storage();
    exports.readFile = (req, res) => {
            console.log('Reading File');
            var archivo = storage.bucket('your-bucket').file('your-JSON-file').createReadStream();
            console.log('Concat Data');
            var  buf = '';
            archivo.on('data', function(d) {
              buf += d;
            }).on('end', function() {
              console.log(buf);
              console.log("End");
              res.send(buf);
            });     

    };
```

I'm reading from a stream and concat all the data within the file to the buf variable.

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

To read multiple files:

```
'use strict';
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
listFiles();

async function listFiles() {
        const bucketName = 'your-bucket'
        console.log('Listing objects in a Bucket');
        const [files] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles();
        files.forEach(file => {
            console.log('Reading: '+file.name);
            var archivo = file.createReadStream();
            console.log('Concat Data');
            var  buf = '';
            archivo.on('data', function(d) {
                buf += d;
            }).on('end', function() {
                console.log(buf);
                console.log("End");
            });    
        });
};
```

Comment: This works if you are reading ONE file. But what if you want to read multiple files.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like what I had at first. But have you tested this? createReadStream seems to go on an async adventure and the result is ballistic :D

I had to trick it with await...

Comment: Yes, that will depend on how big are your files too

Comment: Surprising how long I had to look before someone finally had a working example.  Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

I was using the `createWriteStream` method like the other answers but I had a problem with the output in that it randomly output invalid characters (�) for some characters in a string. I thought it could be some encoding problems.

I came up with my workaround that uses the `download` method. The `download` method returns a `DownloadResponse` that contains an array of Buffer. We then use `Buffer.toString()` method and give it an encoding of `utf8` and parse the result with `JSON.parse()`.

```js
const downloadAsJson = async (bucket, path) => {
  const file = await new Storage()
    .bucket(bucket)
    .file(path)
    .download();
  return JSON.parse(file[0].toString('utf8'));
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear how this answer differs from [the answer added a year before this one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56374129/542251)

Comment: @Nathan did you ever solve the stream invisible characters issue? We have this problem, but we need to use streams b/c they are large files.

Comment: Hi @Liam, I worked on this so long ago but I believe I initially tried to use the solution that you pointed to. However I faced some encoding issue so I had to make some workaround and decided to share it. So the difference would be an additional improvement on the encoding issue.

Comment: Hi @SeanClark, I'm no longer working on this project so unfortunately I don't have further suggestions on this :)

Comment: @Nathan no worries! I was able to solve this problem by using "transformHeader" and .trim() in PapaParse to strip the excel BOM character.

Answer (score 14):

There exists a convenient method:'download' to download a file into memory or to a local destination. You may use download method as follows:

```
const bucketName='bucket name here';
const fileName='file name here';
const storage = new Storage.Storage();
const file = storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName);

file.download(function(err, contents) {
     console.log("file err: "+err);  
     console.log("file data: "+contents);   
});
```

Answer (score 10):

A modern version of this:

```
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage')
const storage = new Storage()
const bucket = storage.bucket('my-bucket')

// The function that returns a JSON string
const readJsonFromFile = async remoteFilePath => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let buf = ''
  bucket.file(remoteFilePath)
    .createReadStream()
    .on('data', d => (buf += d))
    .on('end', () => resolve(buf))
    .on('error', e => reject(e))
})

// Example usage
(async () => {
  try {
    const json = await readJsonFromFile('path/to/json-file.json')
    console.log(json)
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
})()
```