# How to access a specific file and its contents from within Google Cloud Storage

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I need to access a file stored on Google Cloud Storage, this is not a file that is uploaded, instead it is created by a cloud function. I cannot figure out how to access this file using Node.

I have tried many of the things recommended on Stackoverflow.

- [google-cloud TypeError: gcs.bucket is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53032928/google-cloud-typeerror-gcs-bucket-is-not-a-function)
- [Python GAE - How to check if file exists in Google cloud storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525482/python-gae-how-to-check-if-file-exists-in-google-cloud-storage)
- [How to read content of JSON file uploaded to google cloud storage using node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51970205/how-to-read-content-of-json-file-uploaded-to-google-cloud-storage-using-node-js)

Similarly, I have checked out the sample Google project but that only uses read streams and because I am not uploading the file, I couldn't figure out how to use that.

The closest I have gotten is modifing the first [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53032928/google-cloud-typeerror-gcs-bucket-is-not-a-function) to get this

```
var {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
var gcs = new Storage({
  keyFilename: path.join("_file.json"),
  projectId: 'ProjectId'
});

const chosenBucket = gcs.bucket("bucket_name");
var file = chosenBucket('file.json');
```

This causes a TypeError:
`TypeError: bucket is not a function`

How can I access and read the json located within the file?

Comment: Do you know the file name? Do you want to launch this process when the file is write? What's your version of Node?

Comment: Yes I know the file name. I do not need to write to the file at all, just read from it, but it is a file that will be newly created for each instance. It is version 12 of node.

Comment: Also, the permissions on the file are public.

Answer (score 2):

```
const chosenBucket = gcs.bucket("bucket_name");
var file = chosenBucket('file.json');
```

chosenBucket is not a function. It's a `Bucket` object. Do something like this:

```
const chosenBucket = gcs.bucket("bucket_name");
var file = chosenBucket.file('file.json');

const download_options = {
  // The path to which the file should be downloaded, e.g. "./file.txt"
  destination: destFilename,
};
await file.download(download_options)
```

See an example: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/master/samples/files.js