# Google Buckets / Read by line

Tags: gsutil, google-bucket

I know that is currently possible to [download objects by byte range in Google Cloud Storage buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-download-byte-range).

```js
const options = {
  destination: destFileName, 
  start: startByte,
  end: endByte,
};

await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName).download(options);
```

However, I would need to read by line as the files I deal with are `*.csv`:

```js
await storage
  .bucket(bucketName)
  .file(fileName)
  .download({ destination: '', lineStart: number, lineEnd: number });
```

I couldn't find any API for it, could anyone advise on how to achieve the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could not read a file line by line directly from Cloud Storage, as it  stores them as  [objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms#objects) , as shown on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62555054/13171940):

> The string you read from Google Storage is a string representation of a [multipart form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST). It contains not only the uploaded file contents but also some metadata.

To read the file line by line as desired, I suggest loading it onto a variable and then parse the variable as needed. You could use the sample code provided on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51974921/13171940):

```js
const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");
const storage = new Storage();

//Read file from Storage
var downloadedFile = storage
  .bucket(bucketName)
  .file(fileName)
  .createReadStream();

// Concat Data
let fileBuffer = "";
downloadedFile
  .on("data", function (data) {
    fileBuffer += data;
  })
  .on("end", function () {
    // CSV file data
    //console.log(fileBuffer);

    //Parse data using new line character as delimiter
    var rows;
    Papa.parse(fileBuffer, {
      header: false,
      delimiter: "\n",
      complete: function (results) {
        // Shows the parsed data on console
        console.log("Finished:", results.data);
        rows = results.data;
      },
    });
```

To parse the data, you could use a library like [PapaParse](https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse) as shown on this [tutorial](https://medium.com/how-to-react/how-to-parse-or-read-csv-files-in-reactjs-81e8ee4870b0#:%7E:text=4.%20Now%20import%20the%20module).